# Has anyone tried to run Revolutions Enterprise 4 on Fedora or Ubuntu?

Tags: r, ubuntu, fedora

I know that Revolution Analytics recently released the Revolutions 4 IDE for Red Hat Linux, but I was wondering if anyone has tried to run this IDE on either Fedora or even Ubuntu?  I know that Fedora and Red Hat share a similar kernal while Ubuntu used the debian kernel.  If anyone has tried this and got it to work, any instructions or tips on making it work would be appreciated.
Yours,
Krishna

Comment: @Shane, Good point, comment deleted.

Comment: Both Fedora/CentOS/RedHat and Ubuntu/Debian by default use the same kernel, so called "Linux".

Comment: mbq, you clearly never tried to develop one set of (large) binaries across several Linux distros.

Answer (score 0):

I have not but some general observations:

- CentOS is usually the 'tastes just like RHEL but fewer calories' alternative.
- Fedora may work if it keeps enough of the older libraries.
- Ubuntu, Debian, ... could be a stretch.

so your best bet may be to get CentOS running on a headless server, virtual machine, chroot environment, ...

For the record, the problem in unlikely to be the kernel but the number of dynamic libraries the build may depend upon, starting with libc, libstdc++, the X11 libraries etc pp.  Unless of course Revo bundles *everything* in their release in which case your chances may be better.